# Add custom class to attachment in media library grid mode

Tags: attachments, backbone

[image]

In the above screenshot we are in the **media library with grid mode active**. I want to add a custom class depending on the attachment filter `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js`.

For example i hook to the filter:

```
public function wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($response, $attachment, $meta) {
    $response['customClass'] = "i-want-this-class";
    return $response;
}
```

Perhaps it works with Backbone.js to hook into the render process? Or does it need a workaround with `ajaxComplete` and wait until it is rendered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classes added to each element in the media library grid are dinamically generated in the [media-views.js](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/js/media-views.js) file. Particularly, the code that renders the elements is part of the [`wp.media.view.Attachment`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/js/media-views.js#L2656) function. It's a Backbone.js view, so it's possible to extend the library of that view in order to add the classes or other attributes you need to the grid elements.

First the php:

```
//Pass the variable to the javascript file
function wpse223259_filter_wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $response, $attachment, $meta ) {

    $response['customClass'] = "i-want-this-class";

    return $response;

};

add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'wpse223259_filter_wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 10, 3 );


//Enqueue the javascript file that will extend the view
function wpse223259_add_class_to_media_library_grid_elements() {

    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();

    if( 'upload' === $currentScreen->id ) :

        global $mode;

        if( 'grid' === $mode ) :

            wp_enqueue_script( 'add-class-to-media-library-grid-elements', 'your/path/to/the/javascript-file.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); //Edit to match the file location

        endif;

    endif;

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse223259_add_class_to_media_library_grid_elements' );
```

And then the javascript file:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready( function() {

        if ( undefined !== wp.media ) {

            wp.media.view.Attachment.Library = wp.media.view.Attachment.Library.extend({
                className: function () { return 'attachment ' + this.model.get( 'customClass' ); }
            });

        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```